# Missing MainPage.xaml in Xamarin.Forms Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I'm relatively new to Xamarin.Forms, and I've been working on creating a simple cross-platform app. I've noticed in many tutorials and documentation references to a MainPage.xaml file for designing the UI, but when I inspect my Xamarin.Forms project, I can't seem to find this file.

Could someone help me understand why I don't have a MainPage.xaml file in my project, and how I can design the UI for my Xamarin.Forms app without it? Am I missing a step in the project setup, or is there an alternative way to create the UI?

[image]

Comment: the screenshot only shows your Android project.   A XF project usually has three projects in the solution - a shared XF project with the UI and other shared code, and then a project for each platform (iOS, Android, etc).  All XAML files should be in the shared project

Comment: Can you show me example in screenshot?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/deepdive?pivots=windows#anatomy-of-a-xamarinforms-application

Comment: So which one is it? Is it `NotesPage.xaml`?

Comment: If you are missing a XAML file you can just add it in Solution Explorer

Comment: When i run my project only an android system shows up (no app).

Comment: I'd just try creating a new Xamarin Forms app.

Comment: I did but still the same.

Comment: Do you have three projects in your solution like I described?  Are there any build errors or messages shown in the console when you run it?

Comment: Yes the main and android and ios. No there is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you have a `MainPage.xaml` or not depends on what selection you make in this screen when asked to **choose a template**:

[image]

When you select **Blank** you will get a project with a `MainPage.xaml` file.

For the other two choices (**Tabbed** and **Flyout**) the corresponding file will instead be called `AppShell.xaml`.

So when following a tutorial that works with `MainPage.xaml`, choose the **Blank** template for the project.